# Gazebo and Clearpath Husky A200

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, clearpath, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this tutorial on setting up a Husky A200 simulation environment with Gazebo:  http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/ros-gazeborviz-simulation-for-four-wheeled-differential-drive-robot/

Unfortunately, we are not using the same versions of Ubuntu or ROS.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte, and he is using 11.04 and Electric.

I am getting the following errors when I try to execute `rosmake` on the huskyA200_gazebo and huskyA200_teleop stacks, respectively:

---

**- huskyA200_gazebo:**

```
CMakeFiles/huskyA200_base_controller.dir/src/huskyA200_base_controller.o
  In file included from /home/developer/fuerte_workspace/wavelab-multi-robot-mapping-stack-read-only/huskyA200_gazebo/src/huskyA200_base_controller.cpp:32:0:
  /home/developer/fuerte_workspace/wavelab-multi-robot-mapping-stack-read-only/huskyA200_gazebo/include/huskyA200_base_controller/huskyA200_base_controller.h:31:27: fatal error: gazebo/Param.hh: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

---

**- huskyA200_teleop:**

```
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/huskyA200_teleop_keyboard
    /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/huskyA200_teleop_keyboard.dir/src/huskyA200_teleop_keyboard.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
    /usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
    /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

There is much more to the output of the `rosmake` commands, which I can post if needed, but I did not post the full outputs for readability's sake.

Does anyone know:

1. of any other stacks available to simulate Husky A200 with gazebo, or
2. how to alleviate the errors that I am encountering with these particular stacks?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42288/gazebo-and-clearpath-husky-a200/) by [David Kaczynski](https://answers.ros.org/users/2982/david-kaczynski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're going to get it from source, I would use our official code (which Sid's work was merged into): https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/clearpath_husky

It doesn't support Gazebo 1.0 quite yet; I'm actually working through the conversions right now.

EDIT:
Gazebo 1.0 looks good and has been released to Github in the "husky_description" package. Pre-Fuerte launchfiles, xacros, etc are labeled "_prefuerte". Pull requests welcome! :)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-08-27**:
OK, it supports v1.0 now. Starting our test & release process...

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-28**:
@Ryan nice, thanks.  Any feedback on conversion process is appreciated.

**Comment by [David Kaczynski](https://answers.ros.org/users/2982/david-kaczynski/) on 2012-08-29**:
Wow, that was fast.  Thanks for the update, can't wait to give it a shot